# Creating new dataframe with two dataframes which have same indexes and columns

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes(df1, df2):

```
df1:

    col1   col2   col3   col4
A      1      2      3      4       
B      1      2      3      4
C      1      2      3      4
D      1      2      3      4

df2:

    col1   col2   col3   col4
A      2      4      6      8       
B      2      4      6      8
C      2      4      6      8
D      2      4      6      8
```

I want to achieve this:

```
new_df:`

         col1     col2     col3     col4
     df1  df2  df1 df2  df1 df2  df1 df2
A      1    2    2   4    3   6    4   8       
B      1    2    2   4    3   6    4   8
C      1    2    2   4    3   6    4   8
D      1    2    2   4    3   6    4   8
```

I have tried some multiindex methods but I can't get the desired output.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.concat` with keys and [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with `sort_index` on `axis=1`:

```
l = ['df1','df2']
out = pd.concat((df1,df2),axis=1,keys=l).swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

---

```
  col1     col2     col3     col4    
   df1 df2  df1 df2  df1 df2  df1 df2
A    1   2    2   4    3   6    4   8
B    1   2    2   4    3   6    4   8
C    1   2    2   4    3   6    4   8
D    1   2    2   4    3   6    4   8
```

Another possible way is , `df.join` and create Multi-Index by splitting the columns , then sort the index but the first one is cleaner;

```
out1 = df1.join(df2,lsuffix='_df1',rsuffix='_df2')
out1.columns = out1.columns.str.split('_',expand=True)
out1 = out1.sort_index(axis=1)
```

---